# Need help with hard regex

Tags: php, regex, capitalization

I need a regex that checks if a string only contain letters(a-z) and that the first letter is uppercase, you cant have 2 letters in a word uppercase Like: THomas or THomAS but Thomas Anderson (Thomas anderson too) would be valid

look:

`The Magician Of The Elfs` would be valid but not `ThE MaGiCiAN oF ThE ELFS`

```
if (!preg_match("??", $name)) {
   echo "Invalid name!";
}
```

hope you understand!

Tomasz

Invalid:

`MaGIciaN Of The ELFz`
`THomas anderson`

Valid:

`Magician of the elfs`
`Magician Of the Elfs`
`Magician of The elfs`
`Thomas Anderson`
`Thomas anderson`

**Basically i dont want it to be possible to have more than 1 capitalized letter in a word, not sentence.**

Comment: Are you really only looking for the range `a-z`? Note that the character class `[a-z]` does  *not* have the `é` in it, for example.

Comment: Instead of rejecting the invalid names, how about fixing them? You can do $string=ucwords(strtolower($string)); to make the invalid input fit the style you want.

Comment: The space character in the valid example is not in the a-z range.

Comment: Out of interest, what are you trying to achieve?  I hope you're aware that not all names are spelled a single leading capital for each word.  Eg: Ronald McDonald.  You can make a guess, but that's all it will be.

Comment: Just a side note, if this is an anti-"pokemon" solution, your solution will ban Roman numbers (XXVII) and acronyms (UNO) as well. Maybe it's worth allowing ALL CAPITALS, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also describe the character by its [Unicode character properties](http://docs.php.net/manual/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

```
/^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)*$/
```

---

**Edit**    Since you changed your requirements, try this regular expression:

```
/^[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}]\p{Ll}*(?:\s+[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}]\p{Ll}*)*$/
```

Now the first character or each word can be an uppercase letter or a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 5):

```
'/^[A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z][a-z]+)*$/'
```

Untested, though.

**EDIT** Oh, perhaps I misread your question. The above assumes a minimum word length of two. Is "John A" or "A Horse" valid? In that case: `'/^[A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Z][a-z]*)*$/'`.

---

According to updated requirements:

```
'/^[A-Z][a-z]*( [A-Za-z][a-z]*)*$/'
```

Validates *one* capitalized letter followed by any number of lowercase letters. After this, any number of the sequence: space, (possibly an uppercase letter), any number of lowercase letters (at least one letter in total for each space).

Comment: That should do the trick. Note that PHP expects delimiters, which I added.

Comment: Yup, I forgot (and we had a little edit collision). Should be OK now.

Comment: wait, i would like John horse to be valid too

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "ThE MaGiCiAN oF ThE ELFS";
$s = explode(" ",$str);
foreach ($s as $k){
    if ( ! (preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-z]+/",$k) )){
        print "$str does not match.\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow. `\b`, guys.

```
if matches /\B[A-Z]/ then invalid
```

or, to be Unicode aware,

```
if matches /\B\p{Lu}/ then invalid
```

You may want to ensure the whole string matches `/^[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\s]$/` first, to avoid leaving strings like `The (Magic) Elf` as valid.

Comment: So you're proposing to do it in two steps? In that case, I prefer Gumbo and jensgram's solutions (just one fairly intuitive step). If you don't perform the second validation, not just `The (Magic) Elf` would pass, but also strings like `????????` or `11111111122222222` etc.

Comment: That depends on whether the input already is already filtered, because the asker's example doesn't include these cases. (And updated to further simplify the test.)

Comment: In fact, `????????` and `1111111122222222` satisfies the basic requirement "(not) to have more than 1 capitalized letter in a word". There is no words nor capitalized letters in the string, so it passes.

Comment: Nothing in the "valid examples" suggests these are valid, but sure: they could be. I wouldn't put money on it though! :)

Comment: Haha, that's why a precise specification is costly :p

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("\w[A-Z]", $name)) {
    echo "invalid name!";
}
```